# Windows 10 excruciatingly slow with network connected

Tags: windows-10, networking, performance, freeze

The moment I connect my laptop to any network, wired or wireless, it becomes unresponsively slow. Windows Explorer context menu takes up to 60 seconds to appear, opening command prompt works but opening as administrator doesn't, browsing network shares can be fast but then copying/pasting files might hang so badly that explorer detects it has crashed and restarts itself. It seems generally like Windows Explorer and some network configuration are badly incompatible. Has anyone else got experience with this, either with the problem or any resolutions?

I have

- looked into ShellExView for the context menu issues.
- looked into my CentOS/SAMBA server configuration for file browsing issues (though conformed that the issue occurs even when not on that network at all)
- removed all mapped network drives

The machine is a HP Elitebook 8540w running Windows 10 Professional x64 version 2004 build 19041.804

Symptoms:

- Copying files (drag and drop) to network location is very slow
- Deleting files on network location is even slower (Windows or Linux)
- While making file operations, all Windows Explorer instances are locked up
- Windows + E does nothing or crashes machine

Comment: Is only Windows explorer affected or also other programs (especially those that do not make use of the network)?

Comment: It really just seems to be Windows Explorer. Saving/opening networked files in programs seems to be fine

Answer (score 0):

Tentatively, I have discovered that the 'Quick access' menu item had a pinned link to a network folder that has not been accessible for some years. Removing it seems to have single-handedly sorted out all Windows Explorer issues. If this is in fact the resolution then I can only assume that a range of Windows updates over the years have had various dependencies on the quick access link, and the latest update was very dependent.